# How to collect latest value of debounced kotlin flow before cancellation

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have a kotlin flow that emits values at a high rate. I use [debounce](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/debounce.html) to collect the values only when there are no more updates for a while.

```kotlin
val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
scope.launch {
  flow { for (i in 1 until 5) { emit(i); delay(200.milliseconds) } }
    .onEach {println("emitted $it")}
    .debounce(300.milliseconds)
    .collect { println("collected $it") }
}
```

output:

```
emitted 1
emitted 2
emitted 3
emitted 4
collected 4
```

Now, my problem is, that the scope in which the collection runs may be cancelled. In this case, I don't want to loose the most up-to-date value, but "collect" it one last time, without the debounce. So if I cancel after 300ms, expect to collect the value 2, instead of collecting nothing:

```kotlin
// ... same as above
Thread.sleep(300)
scope.cancel()
Thread.sleep(1000)
```

output:

```
// --- expected ---
emitted 1
emitted 2
collected 2

// --- actual ---
emitted 1
emitted 2
```

Also, if I cancel after 1100ms, I don't want to emit the value 4 twice.

How can I achieve my desired behavior?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/debounce.html) on `debounce`, that's already what it does: "Always emits the *latest* value", even with an example.

Comment: Yeah, but this is not the case when the flow is cancelled (as can be seen in my example output)

Comment: This would be an issue with any flow regardless of whether it is debounced--once it's cancelled, it's cancelled. Your collector is gone too so it couldn't collect one more value even if the flow could still emit them. If you don't want coroutines of your CoroutineScope to be cancelled yet, you need to postpone cancelling it.

Comment: The difference is that normally values don't reside in the flow for a long time, so every emitted value also gets collected. This is not the case when cancelling a flow with debounce, as values wait in the debounce buffer for a while. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html#flow-cancellation-checks shows an example of all items of a flow being collected despite it being cancelled mid-way.